# How to make a webserver in a flutter app?

Tags: flutter

I want to make a webserver locally on the flutter android app that can serve a website. Like that i can connect from any computer using the android device's local IP and the website will appear in the browser.

If you are familiar with Airdroid, it has this feature and i want apply it to my app.

**My question is:** Is this possible using dart code or do i need to use MethodChannel with existing android libraries? If so what is the best one out there that i can use?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do. Take a look at the http_server library that was developed by the Dart team.

Here is a code snippet to get you going.

```
HttpServer.bind('0.0.0.0', 8080).then((server) {
  server.transform(HttpBodyHandler()).listen((HttpRequestBody body) async {
    switch (body.request.uri.toString()) {
      case '/':
        String _content = await _loadStatic('index.html');
        body.request.response.statusCode = 200;
        body.request.response.headers.set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
        body.request.response.write(_content);
        body.request.response.close();
        break;

      default: 
        body.request.response.statusCode = 404;
        body.request.response.write('Not Found');
        body.request.response.close();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help mate. Can i get the link to the full code ?

Comment: Seif, sorry. I dont have anything else. That was crafted for the post. I read about this somewhere online that had a more detailed example, but not sure where that is. I saved a snipped in my personal notes when I ran across it incase I ever needed it.

Comment: Thanks either way, i will do my research on this http_server library. I hope i will figure something out.

Comment: What is HttpBodyHandler?